# Laravel-5.1 file Upload to resources folder?

Tags: security, jquery-file-upload, laravel-5.1

I made a multifile upload with laravel 5.1 to public folder, but i need to change this path, because guests are not allowed to access it also each connected user must see only his documents and uploaded files. What i must do ? Thank you.

Comment: can i at least know why the thumb down?

Comment: You provide little to none details, you cannot expect anyone to guess what your underlying code is and help you. Your description of the problem needs much more details, so I suggest you redo it :)

Answer (score 0):

Dear all i found the solution,
For uploading files in a secure way with laravel, i used the storage path.
this may help [Laravel 5.1 upload with storage](http://www.codetutorial.io/laravel-5-file-upload-storage-download/)